# Remove mouse event handler JavaFX

Tags: javafx

I have a code which responses to mouse, for example when I enter in an image area, the image becomes darker and when I exit it, it become normal, problem is when I run the code, I have 9 images and when mouse goes on first image it become darker and when it goes to another image, again the first image goes darker and second image does not change.

Here is the code:

```
public class FrameController implements Initializable {

@FXML
private GridPane album;
ImageView im;

/**
 * Initializes the controller class.
 */
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    // TODO
}

@FXML
private void mouseEntered(MouseEvent event) {
    im = (ImageView) event.getSource();
    System.out.println("Entered: " + im.getId());
    im.setOnMouseEntered(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            ColorAdjust ca = new ColorAdjust();
            ca.setBrightness(-0.5);
            im.setEffect(ca);
            }
        });
    }
    @FXML
    private void mouseExited(MouseEvent event) {
        im = (ImageView) event.getSource();
        System.out.println("Exited: " + im.getId());
        im.setOnMouseExited(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                im.setEffect(null);
                System.out.println("normal");
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: What is your idea? What do you mean with removing the mouse handler?

Comment: Why don't you just remove the `mouseEntered` method and its usage from the fxml?

Comment: @NDY I think my question was dumb, I correct it

Comment: @itachiUchiha I think my question was dumb, I correct it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to check your fxml, but you have a basic mistake in your code. You need to remove the re-use of `onMouseEntered()` and `onMouseExit()`.

Try with

```
@FXML
private void mouseEntered(MouseEvent event) {
    im = (ImageView) event.getSource();
    System.out.println("Entered: " + im.getId());
    ColorAdjust ca = new ColorAdjust();
    ca.setBrightness(-0.5);
    im.setEffect(ca);
}

@FXML
private void mouseExited(MouseEvent event) {
    im = (ImageView) event.getSource();
    System.out.println("Exited: " + im.getId());
    im.setEffect(null);
}
```